# Confusion in known result

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Consider the function

$$ f(x,y)= \frac{x^2-y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2}. $$

Now, if you evaluate the integral

$$ \int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}f(x,y)dydx = \frac{\pi}{4},$$

and if you consider the other order, you get

$$ \int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}f(x,y)dxdy = -\frac{\pi}{4}. $$

So, the iterated integrals exist, but the double integral does not.

My question: Why is  $f$ not integrable? 
It continuous except measure zero set.

Comment: It is not bounded, and both the positive part and negative part have a divergent integral. Hence, this $f$ Riemann integrable (in the generalized sense), but not Lebesgue integrable. Note that the theorem you are evoking doesn't apply since $f$ is not bounded.

Comment: @Crostul: Why not put that as an answer?